# What is the matter with script-targeted URLs?

Tags: javascript, validation, jshint

I'm using JSHint, and it got the following error:

```
Script URL.
```

Which I noticed that happened because on this particular line there is a string containing a `javascript:...` URL.

I know that JSHint complained that because the `scripturl` option is set, and since my codebase is quite large, I'll have to unset it for now.

Still, I don't understood what is the issue of using script URLs?

Comment: @epascarello: He's asking why.

Comment: Hence why I did not make it a answer! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`javascript:` URLs are part of 'eval is evil'.

In order to execute the `javascript:` URL, the browser must fire up a JS parser and parse the text of the URL.
This is a slow and costly process.

Also, assembling `javascript:` URLs (or other strings that contain source code) is a tricky task which is prone to XSS vulnerabilities.

Finally, mixing code and URLs violates the separation of content and behavior (code).

Comment: @Barmar: It needs to parse your `<script>` tag no matter what.  However, it's better to parse one longer script than many shorter ones.

Comment: Doesn't it have to do the same parse if you put the script in `<script>` and call it as a function? It's worse, because it has to parse the JS even if you never click on the link.

Comment: Separation of code and content: isn't it more obvious to insert a script URL than to attach an event to an element, prevent default, and override the apparent content in some hidden place in the code? How else might I submit a form using AJAX?

Comment: "the browser must fire up a JS parser and parse the text of the URL" How can i confirm this statement?

Comment: @tsh: How do you expect the browser to run code without parsing it?

Comment: Browser may want to specially optimize link like `javascript:;` and `javascript:void(0);` since they are quite common.

Comment: Developers may want to write correct HTML since that's what we expect from them.