# Is tabIndex: 0 in links considered a good practice in order to avoid href="javascript: void(0);"?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, tabindex, keyboard-navigation

`a href="javascript: void(0)"` is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497971/what-is-the-matter-with-script-targeted-urls/13498040#13498040) and I can't use `href="#"` in every case, so I'm thinking to add an empty `a` with `tabIndex=0` in order to be accessible with keyboard.

Is it considered a good practice?

P.S. Bootstrap's dropdown needs `<a>` in inner elements for keyboard navigation, so I have to use `<a>`.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you should be using a `<button type="button">...</button>` instead of a link?

Comment: @Kaddath I could but it's used in many cases..it's not so special. I would have to use href="#" and then add prevent default in many files. I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: According to [this WebAIM article](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex), if you make an element focusable via `tabindex="0"`, it **must** support the relevant keyboard interaction (e.g., it should respond to `Enter` or `Space`). By default, at least in Chrome and Firefox, `a` elements with no `href` but with `tabindex="0"` do not (not even with `role="link"` or `role="button"`). So if you do this, ensure that those work (Bootstrap may already do so). I would also suggest that if you do this, you add the appropriate `role` value.

Comment: @Danield As I mentioned in my question, I can't. I have to use `<a>` because that's the way Bootstrap dropdown has implemented keyboard navigation in dropdowns.

Comment: Uh, `href="#"` is not a good practice either. You should put a link to the site that would take you to the actual target of the navigation entry.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t have a `href` then it’s not a link, period.

You can use `<button type="button">` in bootstrap dropdown menu so I recommend you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Tabindex=0 will make your links focusable but not clickable. Instead of just using `#`, use the id attribute of the item which is changing or that you are navigating to. E.g. `<a href="#section2">Step 2</a>` or similar. This way you get the href so the link is both focusable and operable, and when that link is clicked the browser will send the user to that location.