# Apparent race condition with loading javascript content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, typeerror

I am integrating a Finance Calculator from a third party into our website, the integration is shown below. The first 3 files are 3rd party files, and the `pbf-calculator-init.js` is my own file where I initialise the `FinanceCalculator()`.

The weird bit is sometimes the page **perfectly fine** and loads as expected without errors however sometimes it will display an error in the console (shown below)

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')"
```

This error appears on Line `1411` in the `pbf-calculator.js` file, this code hasn't been modified however and when I reload the page it will sometimes load the calculator fine without any errors. It appears that the Finance Calculator that is injected into the page appears to sometimes have some form of race condition and occasionally causing it to not be able to find the `maxLoan` attribute below and therefore returning the error and displaying the calculator correctly.

Line 1411 from the pbf-calculator.js

```
m = d.getAttribute("maxLoan") ? parseFloat(d.getAttribute("maxLoan")) : e.settings.maxLoan ? parseFloat(e.settings.maxLoan) : parseFloat(e.settings.limits.maxLoan),
```

form.tpl (HTML template)

```
<div id="pbf_calculator_container"></div>

<script src="/assets/js/decimal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/pbf-calculator.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/pbf-calculator.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/pbf-calculator-init.js"></script>
```

From [pbf-calculator-init.js](https://pastebin.com/kSZnsZva)

```
financeCalculator({
    target: "div#pbf_calculator_container",
    config: "/assets/js/pbf-calculator-config.json",
    loan_amount_target: ".order-total strong",
    rep_example: {
        cash_price: 8000,
        deposit: 3000,
        loan_amount: 5000,
        apr: 9.9,
        interest_rate: 9.9,
        term: 12,
        instalment_amount: 438.38,
        total_term: 12,
        credit_charge: 260.56,
        total_amount_payable: 8260.56
    },
    colours: {
        primary: "#7D3CFF",
        darker: null
    },
    labels: {
        amount: "Enter the amount you would like to spend",
        deposit: "Enter the amount you would like to deposit",
        service: "Select a finance service",
        term: "Select a repayment term",
        results: "Finance Summary",
        deferralterm: "Select a deferral period"
    },
    classes: {
        buttons: "pbf_button",
        button_wrapper: "pbf_button_wrapper",
        button_list: "pbf_button_list",
        inputs: "pbf_input",
        input_wrapper: "pbf_input_wrapper",
        labels: "pbf_label",
        results_box: "pbf_results"
    }
});
```

Due to the size of `pbf-calculator.js` I have added a pastebin to the file
https://pastebin.com/kSZnsZva

**Expected Outcome**
Page loads the same content every time without returning the js error and no longer has any apparent race conditions so that the Finance Calculator injects into the `div#pbf_calculator_container` as expected.

**Actual Outcome**
Sometimes the page will load as expected and the Finance Calculator works without any console errors, however sometimes there is an apparent race condition and the console reports an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')" error

Comment: Impossible to eyeball debug this. Obviously you are assuming something that is not always correct. So `m = d && d.getAttribute("maxLoan") ? parseFloat(d.getAttribute("maxLoan"))`

Comment: Put the CSS link in the head before any JS perhaps

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the comment, the line I posted is line 1411 which is from the pbf-calculator.js file that can be visible in the pastebin link

Comment: I know it is. When are lines 1004-1005 executed?

Comment: Lines 1004-1005 are part of the createCalculatorMarkup(), this function is called on line 850 -
        i ? checkRepExample(t.rep_example) && (a.colours && createStyleMarkup(a), (a.targetElement = i), createCalculatorMarkup(rebuildSettings(a, "0"))) : console.log("Please define a valid target container for the Finance Calculator");

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no joy but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Not part of your issue but you can remove `type="text/javascript"` since all modern browsers default to that now.

Comment: `setAttributes(r, { type: "radio", name: "term", value: e, onclick: "javascript:updateRadio(this)" }),`  Script URL?  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13497971/125981

Comment: f is undefined here `function printNumber(e) {
    return (f = parseFloat(e)), isNaN(f) ? "\xA3" + e : f.toLocaleString("en-GB", { style: "currency", currency: "GBP", minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
}`

Comment: You might try putting the library JS file links in the head.  Also it is unclear if this does not have an element found: `d = e.querySelector(".term-section > #term label.active > input"),` however, why not just `d = e.querySelector("#term label.active > input"),` since by definition there can only be ONE `#term` in the document

Comment: Also there are at least 4 unused variables in `function validateInputs(e, t) {`